# PostgreSQL substring get string between brackets

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, substring

I have a string, say:

`Product Description [White]`

I want to extract anything inside the brackets (in this case `White`) from that string, using the PostgreSQL Substring function. I can get this to work using `regexp_matches`, but that returns an array which I don't want unless I have no other choice.

I've tried:

- `substring('string' from '[(.)]')` >>> NULL
- `substring('string' from '\[(.)\]')` >>> NULL
- `substring('string' from '\\[(.)\\]')`  >>> NULL

But this works:

- `substring('string' from 'W(.)i]')`  >>> h

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`(.)` only matches a single character, but you want to match multiple characters in there.

So you need `(.+)`

```
substring('Product Description [White]' from '\[(.+)\]')
```

Comment: Only missing one character... Thanks a lot!

Comment: your response helped me a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: How can you do this for all matches in brackets

Comment: This doesn't work with multiple brackets. "Product Description [White][Black] would return White][Black... looking for a way to improve this to fit my needs.

Comment: WHAT IF? substring('Product Description [White] [Blue]' from '\[(.+)\]')

Answer (score -2):

i think you want to update some value like grade pay from pay scale or any thing just use following query

UPDATE master.pay_scale
   SET grade_pay= Case When description LIKE '%(%)%'  Then (select substring(description from '((.+))')) else description End::numeric